# Notepad++ and Regex: How to convert a uppercase sentence in a lowercase sentence?

Tags: regex, notepad++, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to convert my sentences from uppercase to lowercase using notepad++.
If every character in that sentence is uppercase, then convert every character in that sentence to lowercase.

Example:

HOW DO OUR SENTENCE EXAMPLES HELP YOU?
Whether it’s simple sentences for those just learning the English language or phrasing for an academic paper, this easy-to-use sentence generator will help you choose your words with confidence.

Result:
how do our sentence examples help you?
Whether it’s simple sentences for those just learning the English language or phrasing for an academic paper, this easy-to-use sentence generator will help you choose your words with confidence.

I've tried something like [A-Z][A-Z]+ and replace for \l, but it is clear that I still don't understand how it works. Can you guys help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us a precise definition for an uppercase sentence?  Does _every_ character in that sentence have to be uppercase, or could there also be some lowercase letters there?

Comment: Sorry and thanks for telling me, after some minutes I edited it.

Comment: I did it already. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using

```
(?-i)[A-Z][^a-z?!.]*[?!.]
(?-i)[[:upper:]][^[:lower:]?!.]*[?!.]
```

Replace with `\L$0`. Note that `(?-i)` is equal to setting the *Match Case* option in the search and replace UI window.

Both patterns mean

- `[A-Z]` / `[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase letter
- `[^a-z?!.]*` / `[^[:lower:]?!.]*` - zero or more chars other than lowercase letters, `?`, `!` and `.`
- `[?!.]` - a `?`, `!` or `.`

Note that this pattern assumes the sentences do not contain abbreviations.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]